# Does Pandas have a resample method without dependency on a datetime index?

Tags: pandas

I have a series that I want to apply an external function to in subsets/chunks of three. Although the actual external function is more complex, for the sake of an example, lets just assume my external function takes an ndarray of integers and returns the sum of all values. So for example:

```py
series = pd.Series([1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1])
# Some pandas magic similar to:
result = series.resample(3).apply(myFunction)
# where 3 just represents every 3 values and
# result == pd.Series([3,3,3])
```

I looked at combining [Series.resample](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.resample.html?highlight=downsample#pandas-series-resample) and [Series.apply](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.apply.html) as hinted to by the psuedo code above but it appears `resample` depends on a datetime index. Any ideas on how I can effectively downsample by applying an external function like this without a datetime index? Or do you just recommend creating a temporary datetime index to do this then reverting to the original index?

Answer (score 2):

[pandas.DataFrame.groupby](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html#pandas-dataframe-groupby) would do the trick here. What you need is a repeated index to specify subsets/chunks

##### Create chunks

```
n = 3
repeat_idx = np.repeat(np.arange(0,len(series), n), n)[:len(series)]
print(repeat_idx)

array([0, 0, 0, 3, 3, 3, 6, 6, 6])
```

##### Groupby

```
def myFunction(l):
    output = 0
    for item in l:
        output+=item
    return output
series = pd.Series([1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1])

result = series.groupby(repeat_idx).apply(myFunction)
(result)

0    3
3    3
6    3
```

The solution will also work for chunks not adding to the length of series,

```
n = 4
repeat_idx = np.repeat(np.arange(0,len(series), n), n)[:len(series)]

print(repeat_idx)
array([0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 4, 4, 4, 8])

result = series.groupby(repeat_idx).apply(myFunction)
print(result)

0    4
4    4
8    1
```

Comment: In actuality my series is generated with an index that is not an incremental integer, so is there any way of retaining the original index of the series post application of groupby? I would be aiming for dropping all but the center index of each subset (as my chunks are in 3), but not sure how I'd rephrase this for an even chunk value.

Comment: The solution above doesn't use index of the series, the repeat_idx is generated purely using length of series and size of chunks.